# SSH from Windows to Linux without entering a password

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, scp

I am trying to use ssh/scp from Windows to Linux without having to enter a password.

This is what I have done, and it doesn't seem to work:

- generated public and private keys using Putty Key Generator (on Windows)
- saved the files as `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`
- copied them into `~/.ssh`
- added id_rsa.pub to the Linux box in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- I then try to `ssh` to the Linux box from Windows and I still have to enter a password

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

You have to run an authentication agent on Windows.

For example, [Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), used in combination with [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) (graphical SSH client) or Plink (its command line equivalent).

You'll need to tell Pageant your SSH server's public key. After that it will deal with your server's authentication requests while running in the background.

Comment: Note: (This wasn't obvious to me.) When opening Pageant, it will open as an icon in the notification area in the bottom right. Right click it, and click **Add Key**, and select the .ppk file that was generated from puttygen.

Answer (score 13):

I used this:

c:\> `type c:\users\my_name\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh root@172.110.1.171 "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

Comment: But before you must run `ssh-keygen` command

Comment: @Mtl Dev  How to understand `type c:\users\my_name\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh root@172.110.1.171 "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"` in the right way?

Answer (score 11):

You need [Pageant](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

See the video *[Password-less login with PuTTY and Pageant](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xadb3u_passwordless-login-with-putty-and-p_tech)*. And/or the blog post *[Howto: Passwordless SSH authentication with PuTTY](http://www.technlg.net/windows/putty-auto-login-ssh-keys/)*.

Comment: Please try to link to text-based tutorials instead of videos.

Comment: The blog link is broken. Try this one: http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-with-putty/

Comment: The blog link broken is the exact reason answers should be more then a link.

Comment: The blog link is not broken, at least not anymore...

Answer (score 6):

Try Plink (part of PuTTY)

```
 plink -v youruser@yourhost.com -pw yourpw "some linux command"
```

Comment: +1 for a correct response, but you're better off using a public/private key pair than a password.

Comment: Despite the alternative, with **plink** you can't have a normal terminal with it, for example: the arrow keys wont work for the **bash history**

Answer (score 4):

Setting up SSH key authentication can be a bit tricky. It sounds like you're covering all your bases. One thing that often catches people off guard - you need to make sure the `.ssh` directory and its contents are owned by you and are read/writeably only by you.

Make sure to run this (on all your `.ssh` directories):

```
chmod -R 700 on ~/.ssh
```

If that doesn't work, turn on verbose logging by adding `-v` to your `ssh` command (you can add up to three `-vs`s for more verbosity).

Comment: THIS THIS! I used this tutorial to create the key, etc, at: https://www.chrisjhart.com/Windows-10-ssh-copy-id/ but I got all kind of errors, tried converting via puttygen.. All I needed was the chmod.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your keys are not password protected, and what you're getting is not a request for your key's password.

~/.ssh isn't used by putty on the windows side, and putty doesn't have a default private key setting.  If you're using a command line ssh client such as cygwin, creating a .ssh directory off of your home would work.  From putty, you'll need to configure and save a session.

From the putty configuration dialog, look at connection -> data, and fill in the auto-login username field.  Then go to connection -> ssh -> auth, and set your private key correctly.  Then go back to the session dialog, and save this session.  You can also set the hostname if you'd like.

Once you have a saved session, you can use 'putty -load "savedsession"'.

Comment: Also, chmod 700 ~/.ssh on the target machine, and chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized keys.  Once I followed your instructions and set the permissions correctly, it started working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You may also need to change permissions on your home directory:

```
chmod 755 ~
```

Answer (score 2):

**git for Windows** installs the cross-platform `ssh` tools you need:

- `ssh-keygen`
- `ssh-copy-id`.

Depending your preference of bash or PowerShell,

Either do this from the git-installed `bash` shell:

```
#By default this puts keyfile pair in ~/.ssh/id_rsa & ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub :

ssh-keygen.exe -t rsa -b 2048 
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  $remoteuser@$remotehost

# These two chmod lines are needed on unix platforms, probably not on Windows. 
# typically ssh refuses to use a private key file 
# if it is less-well protected than this:
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 640 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Or run this script in PowerShell:

```
Param(
  [Parameter()][string]$keyfile="id_rsa",
  [Parameter()][string]$remotehost,
  [Parameter()][string]$remoteuser
  )
write-host "# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#"
write-host "# Create an RSA public/private key pair, and copy the public key to remote server  #"
write-host "#                                                                                  #"
write-host "# https://superuser.com/questions/96051                                            #"
write-host "#         ssh-from-windows-to-linux-without-entering-a-password/1194805#1194805    #"
write-host "#                                                                                  #"
write-host "# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#"

write-host "Keyfile pair will be saved at : ~/.ssh/$keyfile, ~/.ssh/$keyfile.pub"
write-host "And copied to $remoteuser@$remotehost"
write-host ""
write-host "You will need a password for the copy operation."
write-host ""

if( -not $(ls ~/.ssh) ) { mkdir ~/.ssh }
$sshdir=$(get-item ~/.ssh/).Fullname

#By default this puts keyfile pair in ~/.ssh/id_rsa & ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub :
ssh-keygen.exe -t rsa -b 2048 -f "$sshdir$keyfile"

# ssh-copy-id somehow didn't work in Powershell so I called it via bash
bash -c "ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/$keyfile.pub $remoteuser@$remotehost"

# I'm not sure if these two chmod lines work on windows but 
# typically ssh refuses to use a private key file 
# if it is less-well protected than this:
chmod.exe 700 $sshdir
chmod.exe 640 "$sshdir$keyfile"
```

After this, passwordless login should work for both `ssh` and `scp`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this exactly from `Windows 7` by using the `-i` option for supplying an identity private key:

> ssh -i X:\win-path\to\private-key remoteuser@remote.host.com

except that on the remote host, my authorized keys are in `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys/remoteuser` and in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I changed

```
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
```

but I don't know if the SSH remote config should matter.