# Unable to connect using PuTTY ssh

Tags: putty

I'm on a Windows 7 machine and have installed PuTTY. I'm trying to connect, but the authentication fails because of an incorrect password. But, the VM I'm connecting to doesn't have a password?

Here are the creds I'm trying to use:

- **Host**: 127.0.0.1
- **Port**: 2222
- **Username**: vagrant
- **Private key**: c:/users//.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key

When I open PuTTY, I put in the above credentials and click open, at which point it ask for the username and I enter `vagrant`, then it asks for the password, but there isn't a password, so I get access denied?

Not sure how to get around this?

Comment: What fields are you filling in PuTTY?  How are you giving PuTTY your private key?  If you haven't specified a private key prior to connecting, most ssh servers will default to a password login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need is a key that PuTTY can understand.  PuTTY requires a .ppk file, which is not the same as the standard openSSH key file.  You can use the PuTTYgen tool to generate a key or to convert an existing openSSH to a putty key.

Once you have a key, you need to tell PuTTY about it.  For this you have two options:

- [Specifiy a key directly](https://superuser.com/a/12683/820)
- [Use Pageant to store keys](https://superuser.com/q/96051/820)

Once you have PuTTY all setup, you need to make sure you have [added your public key](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-gettingready) to the `authorized_keys` file.  Once that is all setup you should be able to connect.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that could be at play:

**On the *"Server"***

Have you verified that the public key is in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` of the `vagrant` user?

A simple way to add:

```
cat id_aribtratry_name.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys{,2}
```

(Shell expansion should do both, but may as well double check the files).

**On the *Host***

Nothing above suggests to me that you used [Puttygen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to get the key for Putty, also you can configure putty to skip asking you the other things.

1. Using Puttygen

   Open Puttygen: File > Load Private Key (in the pop-up dialog, you will need to select "All Files") to load your key.

   [image]

   Leave everything as it is and click "Save private key"

   [image]

   It will prompt you to confirm you don't want a password, I will leave that option up to you.  Locally, not really a problem.  But a server online - I would suggest it.

   Save it wherever as `id_whatever.ppk`
2. Set up Putty (saves you time later)

   Enter the IP and Port (As you have been doing)

   [image]

   On the left, navigate to Connection > SSH > Auth, find your private key file in the  "browse" dialog.

   [image]

   Navigate back to Connection > Data, specify your Auto-login username

   [image]

   Finally, go back to Session, and you can specify a name to save the session under.

   [image]

After all that, you should be able to login.  That is, assuming the IP is correct.  To avoid confusion, I personally would use the actual IP of the machine. But if the LO works through the other port, that is fine to use.

Answer (score -1):

your VM should have a different IP, not your loopback address.

Edit: from my experience with VMWare.  I can't speak for all virtualization software.

Comment: To clarify. Each and every IP v4 host has an IP numbered 127.0.0.1 which leads back to itself. Both your windows 7 host and the vm should have 127.0.0.1 **and** another IP. Those other IPs differ.

Comment: @Bryan, he is likely using a VM running on a virtual NAT, which would explain why he's using port 2222 likely forwarded to port 22 on the guest.

Comment: I created a VM on my machine to provide a specific rails development environemnt on my machine.  See githbu here: https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box  I'm pointing to the private key file under my user directory.  I think the issue is PuTTY is expecting the private key in a different format perhaps?

Comment: Vagrant forwards ports for SSH automatically, from 127.0.0.1 to the VM.